# Writing a hyperlink field to another sheets range within a loop using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am currently trying to get VBA syntax for writing Hyperlink to a range on an existing worksheet. I have code that I believe should work, but I just can't seem to manage to get it to work how it should. Any help with this would be great. Below is the code that I can't understand why it isn't working.

```
Sheets("EmailDataOutput").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Sheets("EmailDataOutput").Range("h" & outputrow), Address:="https://rocketsutoledo.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/Project%20Detail%20Pages/Schedule.aspx?ProjUid=" & projid, ScreenTip:="", TexToDisplay:="Click here to go to Project"
```

Thanks in advance for any help,

Jacob

Comment: Are there any error when run the code? If so, please check what `outputrow` shows, when stopped on error and move the cursor over it. If not and it only does not follow hyperlink when clicked, do you receive any error (message). Trying to manually acces the site in discussion, does it work? I mean using `projid` from the above code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: You have two variables in this code `outputrow` and `projid` that you should put values for them.

```
With Worksheets("EmailDataOutput") 
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("h" & outputrow), _ 
 Address:="https://rocketsutoledo.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/Project%20Detail%20Pages/Schedule.aspx?ProjUid=" & projid, _  
 ScreenTip:="", _
 TextToDisplay:="Click here to go to Project" 
End With
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! I was able to insert this code and it worked like a charm within my loop! Thank you so much for the help. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome @Jacob.b20. So, you can Mark this Answer as "Accepted". https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers